# Compilation error when registering callbacks in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, callback

I've just started learning openGL a couple of hours ago for my work and have been tasked with rendering a concave polygon using tessellation.  I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
#ifndef CALLBACK
#define CALLBACK
#endif

#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"

void CALLBACK beginCallback(GLenum which);

void drawHook()
{
   GLUtesselator* tessObj = gluNewTess();
   gluTessCallback(tessObj, GLU_TESS_BEGIN, beginCallback);
}

void CALLBACK beginCallback(GLenum which)
{
    glBegin(which);
}
```

which I've gotten from the [OpenGL Programming Guide, Seventh Edition](http://www.amazon.co.uk/OpenGL-Programming-Guide-Official-Learning/dp/0321552628), with the relevant chapter also being [available online](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter11.html). But the following error is being returned:

```
hook.cc:28: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(GLenum)’ to ‘void (*)()’
hook.cc:28: error: initializing argument 3 of ‘void gluTessCallback(GLUtesselator*, GLenum, void (*)())’
```

This error leads me to believe that the third argument of `gluTessCallback` should be a function that takes no arguments, yet the 'official' openGL reference states otherwise.

Am I missing something here or is the book incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is correct. You just have to cast the function pointer to `void(*)()`. It's needed because the type is not (and cannot be) precise.

```
gluTessCallback(tessObj, GLU_TESS_BEGIN, (void(*)())&beginCallback);
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you linked states that the third argument of `gluTessCallback` is a parameterless function. (right after the heading *Tessellation Callback Routines*)

However, Example 11-1 casts the actual function pointer to a parameterless one:

```
gluTessCallback(tobj, GLU_TESS_ERROR, (GLvoid (*) ()) &errorCallback);
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```